# How do I check Bazel version?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to find out which version of Bazel I currently have on my computer to install TensorFlow from source (it requires version 0.1.4)

```
evan@evan-box:~/Apps/tensorflow$ bazel --version
Unknown Bazel startup option: '--version'.
  For more info, run 'blaze help startup_options'.
evan@evan-box:~/Apps/tensorflow$ bazel version
Build label: head (@125b349)
Build target: bazel-out/local_linux-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/bazel-main_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Nov 13 01:23:30 2015 (1447377810)
Build timestamp: 1447377810
Build timestamp as int: 1447377810
```

So where is the version actually?

Answer (score 26):

See [Bazel users manual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html)

From the command line:

```sh
$ bazel version 
Build label: 0.1.1
```

Comment: The result `head (@125b349)` looks like a `Git` commit. You should be able to get the version from the commit [pages](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commits/master?page=1) using the head. I looked for it on a few pages but could not find it.

Comment: head version means that you built it yourself from head at commit @125b349.

Comment: I get the same versionless output, only without the git hash and the build timestamp in the output is zero. This is after  following [the official apt-get laden Ubuntu installation instructions from here](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/install.html#install-on-ubuntu) on Ubuntu 14.04. Maybe the APT provided is outdated for 14.04 or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

Since bazel version `0.27.0` there is `bazel --version` available, without the side-effect of starting the server daemon.